# Arduino 4-20ma Accuracy

Tags: arduino

I am connecting a pressure transmitter Dwyer MS-121(Have a Range of -100 Pa to +100Pa) to Arduino using 2 Wires Current Loop. For the shunt resistor, I am using 220Ohm. So to calculate from voltage to pressure, this is what I do:
reading is what I read from the shunt resistor

```
(((((float)reading * 0.0049) - 0.88) / 3.52) * 200) - 100)
```

0.0049 is used to know the real voltage, then 0.88 from the bottom range of 4-20mA(4mA * 220Ohm), 3.52 from the top range of 4-20ma(20mA & 220Ohm) and substracted by 0.88 to get a range from 0 to 3.52(So I can calculate it by percentage). Then 200 because the range of my pressure transmitter ( -100 to +100Pa). And the last is substracting it by 100 so I can get a nice range of -100Pa to +100Pa.

Now, My pressure transmitter has display too. The value I got from display is -19.4Pa and I got the value from Arduino is -21.1Pa. It has a difference by 1,7Pa or 0,85%. I am curious why the value from arduino is inaccurate, is it my calculation, or my circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 220 ohm resistor is probably only specified as accurate to 5%.  And all of your analog readings are relative to the Arduino's 5V power supply, which itself is probably only accurate to 5%.  So your 8.8% result (not sure how you got 0.85%) is within the expected range, just considering these two possible sources of error.

You are making at least one calculation error: that 0.0049 is just an approximation, the actual voltage conversion factor is 5/1024.  That's 3.5% off right there.

Comment: I got the 0.85% from 1.7Pa / 200 from range equals to 0.0085 or 0.85%. I want to know how you get the 8.8%. Anyway, I saw the resistor and It has Gold Band or 5% tolerance, I haven't thought of that, Thank you so much, it makes sense now. And for the 0.0049, should I change it to 5 / 1024 to remove that 3.5%? and where did you get the 3.5% calculation too, thanks.

Comment: The 1.7Pa error is about 8.8% of the correct value.  Comparing to the entire range isn't really meaningful - if the sensor had 10 times as much measurement range, would that make it 10 times more accurate, even with the same 1.7Pa error?  Likewise, the difference between 0.0049 and 5/1024 is 3.5% of the proper value, 5/1024.  (Make sure you write it as 5.0/1024 in your code, as an integer division the value is zero!)

Comment: I am trying using this (((((float)reading * (5.0 / 1024)) - 0.88) / 3.52) * 200) - 100). Now the difference is about 2.07Pa (21.27 from 19.2 Pa) or 10.78%. I am not sure what happens. Anyway, I am checking the analogRead, it got 465 (the end value will be 21.27) and then I do some calculation and to get the same value as the display I need the analogRead to be 472.